# Copy AutoFiltered Data Loop Until End

Tags: vba, loops, filter, macros

[Data to Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDjcq.jpg)

Hi,

I have created a macro file linked to a script. I would like it to filter the Fiscal Year Column  from the first fiscal year and copy it to another sheet then loop it until all fiscal year have been processed.

I made a repetitive actions in the module but if I remove one of the fiscal year, it won't continue.

How do I filter the criteria with the available fiscal years and it will loop until the end? My problem is the code below since it only specifies one fiscal year.

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$20").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="2012"

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will help you loop through the Years Filter.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Loop_FiscalYear()

Dim Sht                     As Worksheet
Dim Year_Loop               As Integer
Dim Year_Start              As Integer
Dim Year_Finish             As Integer

' modify Sheet1 to your sheet name
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

' modify these parameters according to your needs
Year_Start = 2012
Year_Finish = 2016

For Year_Loop = Year_Start To Year_Finish
    Sht.Range("$A$1:$D$20").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Year_Loop

    ' do your other stuff here.....

Next Year_Loop

End Sub
```

**Edit 1**: Option Code number 2, count number of visible rows per Filtered Year

```
Sub Loop_FiscalYear()

Dim Sht                     As Worksheet
Dim Data_Rng                As Range
Dim Year_Loop               As Integer
Dim Year_Start              As Integer
Dim Year_Finish             As Integer
Dim VisibleRows             As Long
Dim Last_Row                As Long
Dim Last_Col                As Long
Dim RngArea

' modify Sheet1 to your sheet name
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5") ' ("Sheet1")

' remove all filters from table's data
Sht.Range("C1").Select

If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End If

' find last row in sheet
Last_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

' find last column in sheet
Last_Col = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set Data_Rng = Sht.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Last_Row, Last_Col))

' modify these parameters according to your needs
Year_Start = 2012
Year_Finish = 2016

For Year_Loop = Year_Start To Year_Finish

    With Data_Rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Year_Loop
        .Select

        ' count number of rows in Filtered area
        For Each RngArea In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
            VisibleRows = VisibleRows + RngArea.Rows.Count
        Next

        ' MsgBox just for easy debug
        MsgBox "Autofilter " & VisibleRows - 1 & " rows "

        If VisibleRows = 0 Then
            ' do something...

        End If
    End With

    ' reset value for Next year loop
    VisibleRows = 0

Next Year_Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Shai Rado for your help. This works for my macro. I only removed the Option Explicit since I experienced "compile error variable not defined". I would also like to ask if  how I can set that it will go to the next fiscal year if it happens that there are no data for a certain fiscal year?

Comment: @cameri see edited code, it will loop through the years and filter your table, later it will show you how many rows there are per year. I am not sure what you want to do in case it is 0, or if it's not 0 ?

Comment: in case it is 0, I want it to proceed to the next fiscal year. if it is not 0 then just proceed as it is until the end. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: @cameri sorry, but I am not following what you need. Anyway, I think I have answered your original post

Comment: In case one of the fiscal years has no data, say for example we omit the 2014 fiscal year in the data I provided, then I want it to go to the 2015 fiscal year immediately.

Comment: Yes, you have answered my original post. :) Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: @cameri open a new post, and just add the code you currently have, and have screen-shots with details what you would like to do.

Comment: Thanks Shai! I posted another question. Proceed to Next Filter if Rows are Empty.